# How to add a masked password property to a BizTalk custom file adapter?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I've built a custom file adapter using the sample found in the BTS 2009 SDK, but I need to receive files via this adapter using credentials other than what the host instance is running under.  I'd like to add 2 properties to the properties window of the adapter for username and password (this I know how to do), but I want to hide the password text on the password property.  Does anyone know how to go about this?  Is there something I can set in the ReceiveLocation.xsd on the property to let it know it's for a password, similar to TextBox.PasswordChar property?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to use a custom file adapter? The standard file adapter has the option to specify different credentials.

Comment: Yes, I'm receiving files from an iSeries file share, and the standard file adapter doesn't work properly for this due to a slight difference with the events raised by IFS as opposed to a Windows fs.

Comment: I would like to be able to specify different credentials in the same manner as the standard file adatper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to use the Biztalk Adapter Framework PasswordUITypeEditor and PasswordTypeConverter components in the ReceiveLocation.xsd like so:

```
 <xs:element name="Password">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <baf:designer>
                  <baf:displayname _locID="passwordName">Password</baf:displayname>
                  <baf:description _locID="passwordDesc">Enter username for authentication to directory</baf:description>
                  <baf:editor assembly="%BTSROOT%\\Developer Tools\\Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.dll">Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.ComponentModel.PasswordUITypeEditor</baf:editor>
                  <baf:converter assembly="%BTSROOT%\\Developer Tools\\Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.dll">Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Framework.ComponentModel.PasswordTypeConverter</baf:converter>
                  <baf:category _locID="authenticationCategory">Endpoint Directory Authentication</baf:category>
                </baf:designer>
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:maxLength value="22" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
```

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, just what I needed.